# unable to update reverse relation fields in update UpdateAPIView django rest

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I have profile models related to user

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    stream_name = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True)
```

**serializerr.py**

```
class ProfileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    first_name = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    last_name = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    def get_first_name(self, profile):
        return profile.user.first_name

    def get_last_name(self, profile):
        return profile.user.last_name

    class Meta:
        model = htu_models.Profile
        exclude = ('id', 'user')
```

**view.py**

```
class UserProfileChangeAPIView(generics.RetrieveAPIView, generics.UpdateAPIView):
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticated,)
    serializer_class = api_serializers.ProfileSerializer
    # parser_classes = (MultiPartParser, FormParser,)

    def get_object(self):
        obj = get_object_or_404(User, email=self.request.user.email)
        return obj.profile

    # def put(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    #     return self.update(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def update(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        instance = self.get_object()
        instance.user.first_name = request.data.get("first_name")
        instance.user.last_name = request.data.get("last_name")
        instance.save()

        serializer = self.get_serializer(instance, data=request.data)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        self.perform_update(serializer)

        return Response(serializer.data)
```

this my code **GET** the profile details and user first name and last name but **PUT** request only updating  profile details but not user first name and last name (this reverse relation) **what is the reason ?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you're saving only profile model, not user.
You need to add 
`instance.user.save()`
after setting first and last name.

Also, if all you need is adding one field, maybe it'll be better to inherit from the abstract user instead of O2O.
You can read more here
https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2018/01/18/how-to-implement-multiple-user-types-with-django.html
if you're interested